# tikzset causes `[]pgf@stop` on output

Tags: tikz-pgf

I added the tikz as below to my my code:

```
\tikzset{
->,
>={Stealth[round]},
shorten >=1pt,
thick,
node distance=3cm,
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
initial text=$ $,
}
```

But it led to showing `[]pgf@stop` on my output. As below:

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I would do a rough guess that you should put curly brackets around the value of `initial text`: `{$ $}`.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: This is a very nice example of why it is absolutely necessary to add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including packages and libraries loaded, in order to understand the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have gotten an error message in the log file. Never ignore error messages.

If I add just that `\tikzset` to a minimal example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
->,
>={Stealth[round]},
shorten >=1pt,
thick,
node distance=3cm,
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
initial text=$ $,
}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'Stealth'.
```

This is because the arrow tip `Stealth` is not defined by default, you need to add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` to the preamble to make it available. Skipping past the errors gives the output you described.

If I add just that library, I get a new error,

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/initial text', to  which you passed '$ $', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

After a quick search in the manual, it appears that the `initial text` key is defined by the `automata` library. I don't know if you already had that in your document, as you didn't show a complete example, but the following compiles without errors, and doesn't give the erroneous output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  automata
}
\tikzset{
->,
>={Stealth[round]},
shorten >=1pt,
thick,
node distance=3cm,
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
initial text=$ $,
}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```